# What can I use to strain gritty bloody mary mix?

Tags: equipment, drinks

I like Zing Zang bloody mary mix, but it's very gritty with seasoning.  I like to pour it into a strainer to filter out the grit, but the mix is so thick that it takes forever to strain.  Not only that, it doesn't get all the grit.  A strainer with smaller holes would help keep out more grit, but the thickness of the mix would make it impossible.

I've thought of adding a cup of water to the mix to thin it out, but then I'd have to boil out the water and I don't know how to measure how much water I've boiled out nor do I know what effect boiling would have on the flavor of the bloody mary.

Any ideas?

**Update:** It's looking like my only option so far is to get a high-grade blender that I can use to pulverize a entire bottle of premade mix.

Comment: Boiling it would cook away the alcohol. It's probably not a good idea to boil it but if you do, make sure you do it BEFORE you add the alcohol.

Comment: It's just the mix.  Once I get the mix just right, then I add it.

Comment: Did you try to press it with a ladle or something similar, while straining it?

Comment: That's what I end up doing and I end up having to spend quite a bit of time cleaning the grit out of the screen =\

Comment: Tomato juice + spice, why bother with the mix?

Comment: Personally, I like to use Demitri's bloody mary mix. I pour it into my Magic Bullet and blend it real good to smooth it out then pour a spoonful in tomato juice.  The problem is that I can only get it online and it's expensive with the shipping, so I get premade mixes like Zing Zang.  It's easy to blend the grit out of Demitri's because the quantity is to small as opposed to the premade mixes.

Answer (score 1):

Line a salad spinner with cheese cloth or another lightweight cloth. Fill and spin.

Comment: I like the idea, but, as I said to another answerer, cheese cloth would most likely not allow the thickness of the mix to pass through.  As it is, I have to use a rubber spatula just to push the mix through a mesh strainer.

Comment: The idea of using the salad spinner is that the spinning action will force the mix through the cloth.

Answer (score 0):

Pour the mix in something like a coffee grinder and grind it into a fine powder.

I didn't realize that your mix was liquid.  For liquid, go for something like a Vitamix or such if you want assured pulverized results.

Comment: I've done this with my Magic Bullet, but it's not as effective as I'd like it to be.  I think that if I had a better blender/grinder, this idea would be perfect.  Any idea on a device that would do this job very well?

Comment: Well, as rfusca mentioned, a coffee grinder. Perhaps a mortar and pestle could do the trick too. Or a simple rolling pin could be better than nothing, I think.

Comment: Actually, I didn't make it clear that this mix is in liquid form and not powdered form.  When I go to blend it, whatever blender I use needs to be able to accept liquid.  I am not sure that a coffee grinder is meant for that.  However, I bet a high-grade blender would do well in turning the grit into virtual nothingness.  I have been wanting to spend a couple hundred on a really good blender, so maybe it's time to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using something like fine grade cheesecloth would let the liquid flow through easily enough but still catch a reasonable amount of the solid particles?

Comment: A mesh straner is hard enough.  I don't think a cheese cloth would even allow the thick mix through without the grit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the PERFECT solution to my dilemma.  Here it is:

[image]

I fill it as full as I can with the mix (it's liquid and comes in a bottle) and then tap it downward on top of my glass.  The combination of gravity and momentum caues the mix to easily make it through the mesh of the strainer as soon as it encounters the shock from making contact with the glass.  Doing it this way lets me enjoy a smooth, grit-free bloody mary!